# Drupal: No themes are rendering

Tags: css, drupal, themes

I had a similar problem once after activating Ubercart modules. Certain pages would not render the theme, though all the content was there. I went into performance settings and optimized CSS and all was fine. I heard this was due to too many css files being called at once. The optimize CSS setting streamlines them.

Today though I went tweak a css file and the theme broke again. I restored my edits and still no luck. So I tried other themes including zen and garland and still they all seem to be broken; none of them are rendering though all my contend is there. I've also tried various settings under performance and cleared the cache.

I should also note I'm having the same issues in various web browsers.

I'm not sure it is relevant but I this is a pre-production site online. I moved the directory path recently, but other than a few absolute links I had to change all came out OK. But I wonder if the path to my themes somehow might be an issue?

Thanks in advance for any advice...

Comment: Try checking the code (i.e., View Source in the browser...you'll have to disable CSS aggregation for it to be meaningful) if it's calling the selected theme's CSS files or not, and if so, see where they actually are vs. where Drupal is looking for them.

Comment: I played around more today and the CSS links are in order.  It seems though that not all the CSS is disappearing, but the themes don't' display correctly. 

Anyway, I think I found the culprit: it's the shopping cart block. Whenever I activate it, in any region, the theme fails. If I disable it the themes work. 

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Did you theme this block? In standart it's all correct...
p.s. Just show link to your site, i can say where it is broken.

Comment: I did not theme the block Nikit. But it is all working now, and I think it was a combination of things. I just upgraded to Drupal 6.1.5 and ran update.php. It didn't work at first but now it all does on both IE and Firefox. I think though perhaps when I did what I did and flushed all the caches I forgot to clear the browser cache. I did refresh the pages though so I'm not sure that was the cause. Sorry to be so vagues but this is a new client and I could not post the link publicly. 
Important I remember also that you can't work on the theme files while the optimize CSS option is enabled.

Comment: you will wonder, if you will use Firebug for Firefox browser, that give possible to change css styles dynamically, even it is optimized CSS.

Comment: I'm wondering if you running out of memory, or there's a run condition that preventing all your php from executing. What is your php memory currently set to? OR, are you seeing errors in your apache log as it relates to executing or accessing resources?

Answer (score -1):

Without seeing your broken site we cannot say that happen.